# How can I remove blank lines in an array generated that show in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, loops, filter, null

I have a dropdown that is generated using javascript and html.  I have some code which I will post below that loops through this list and should potentially remove any blank lines found but is not working.  "$maxfield1rows" has a value of 7, what I am saying is that if the value is a blank (=='') then remove it.  I used removeChild but this doesn't seem to work, I also tried splice, I think filter can work but am not sure.  I tried the disabled=true but that just makes them disabled and unselectable. Can someone please help?

```
for(index=1; index<$maxfield1rows; index++) {
  if(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value=='') {    
document.pickDivision.field1.removeChild(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);
  }
}
```

Updated below, I'm using $maxfield1rows since that is the amount of maximum number of rows the the loop goes through, also by change I meant that there is an onchange event that gets triggered when the user selects a different option in the dropdown menu, so depending on the option selected the output for field1 changes, sometimes there are 5 values that show and sometimes just 1:

```
for(index=$maxfield1rows-1; index>=0; index--) {
    alert(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);
    if(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value==''){
        document.pickDivision.field1.removeChild(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);             
        document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=true;
    }
    else{
        document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do a `console.log('a' + document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value + 'b')`, is there a space between a and b or no space?

Comment: Also, looping forwards through the options array and removing items will cause an issue in some (if not all) browsers.  When that item is removed, it is essentially removed from the `options` collection.  This will cause your next item to not be at the same index location.

Comment: There is no space between a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, I think the issue is that you are looping forwards through the options array.  I am surprised that no error is being thrown when you try to do this.  You should loop backwards through the collection to keep from skipping an item.

[JS Fiddle demonstrating the error](http://jsfiddle.net/56x2t/).  In the example, items 1 and 2 are blank and item 3 is not.

These built in collections are changed each time your add/remove an item.  Using the example in the fiddle, my array changes from `[1,2,3]` to `[2,3]` to `error no item at index 2`.

Looping backwards, my collection takes this change: `[1,2,3]` to `[1,3]` to `[3]`.

Here is the code with comments explaining what each part of the for loop is used for and why.  You can use a while loop if you prefer too.

```
//options.length - 1 because arrays are 0 based
//i >= 0 because you don't want to use a negative index on an array
//i-- to loop backwards
for(var i = document.pickDivision.field1.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //Is this an empty item
    if(document.pickDivision.field1.options[i].value == '') {
        //Remove the empty item
        document.pickDivision.field1.removeChild(document.pickDivision.field1.options[i]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

With the newly updated code you posted, you are attempting to access an option element after it has been removed.  From the looks of the line, you don't need it anymore as you are already removing the element.  If you do still want to disable the element before removing it, move that line above the other line (see comment in code).

```
for(index=$maxfield1rows-1; index>=0; index--) {
    alert(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);
    if(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].value==''){
        document.pickDivision.field1.removeChild(document.pickDivision.field1.options[index]);             
        //This line is causing the issue; move it above the previous line or remove it
        document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=true;
    }
    else{
        document.pickDivision.field1.options[index].disabled=false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Per the question in the comments, when you change the number of options to 6, your code breaks.  This is because you are using the hard coded PHP value `$maxfield1rows`.  Since you already know the name of the form and the name of the field in the form, I would recommend you use the length of the options collection in your for loop rather than this variable.  This will make sure that no matter how many option elements there are (1, 10, 1000), you will always loop through the entire collection.

`for(var i = document.pickDivision.field1.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`

Comment: Hmm...I must be doing something wrong I'm getting 'document.pickDivision.field1.options[...] is null or not an object'

Comment: Before the if statement, do a `console.log(document.pickDivision.field1.options[i]);`.  See if it is the first item or the last item that prints null.  Make sure you have the `-1` when setting `i`.

Comment: I just tried and when the dropdown loads it has values so we are okay there it shows 'object' as the output but in the next case when I change the value then I get 'object' but then it just stops and gives the javascript error.  I think you are doing it correctly, there has to be something from my side specifically.

Comment: @niceguy I'm not sure what you mean by `when I change the value I get object`.  If you would update your question with the actual code that is executing, I might be able to see the issue.

Comment: sorry I know I didn't explain, I've put the updated code above, not sure if that will help, please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I think what is happening is that when a user changes an option and in those cases where only 1 value comes up the others are blanks and thus gives the  'document.pickDivision.field1.options[...] is null or not an object' error?

Comment: Great, that definitely worked.  Now I guess the only problem I have is that when I change the option again and select something that has lets say 6 values then I get the error ' 'document.pickDivision.field1.options[...] is null or not an object' again possibly because the element has been removed?

Comment: Thanks, your method is working, there must be more to my code because after making an option change I still get that error.  I will try to look into this

Comment: @niceguy You are welcome.  If you need more assistance figuring out what is causing the issue later on in your code, just ask another question here on SO and post the link in the comments here.  I'd be happy to look at it.